# does mysql write requested modification to file system before return success to client

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

I know that databases systems usually come with a bufferpool. when request received ,the DBMS usually try to locate relevant stuff in the buffer pool ,if not it will tries to load related data into the bufferpoll. If the request tries make modifications to a table,DBMS will modify the corresponding pages in the bufferpool . I am wondering does mysql send success back to client immediately after the bufferpool was modified or after modifications was saved to file system ?
If the DBMS send success back to client immediately after bufferpool was modified ,how does the DBMS handle failure that occured when write dirty pages to the hard drive ?

Comment: You appear to be asking about InnoDB, and if that is true, you should clarify, and you may want to read about the [redo log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-redo-log.html).

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your [`flush`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_flush) server setting, but normally it's set to get a confirmation back from the OS that the changes have been written through to disk. MySQL does not write to the disk buffer and call it done.

You can alter this behaviour, and there's other flags of a similar nature for each engine, like InnoDB specifically.